# Android Application drains battery too fast

Tags: android, accelerometer, battery

The android application I am developing needs to read the info from the sensors, mostly the accelerometer. I want my application to be able to get the info from the sensors, but I do not want the phone's screen to be constantly on because this drains the battery very fast. I need to find a way for the phone to read the info from the sensors, but remain locked or in sleep. The application is supposed to be running in the background constantly and be reading this info. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: Can a service still use sensor's info but still be in sleep mode?

Comment: Service is executed in background, it doesn't have any gui, so it doesn't draing battery. So, as I understand your intention yes, it can.

Comment: I apologize, I am a beginner developer. I actually only designed the application. Our programmers are having this issue, and for some reason cannot solve it. Is there anyway you can help?

Comment: Just to add that it still will drain battery! Not as much, but it will waste battery anyway. Can't you read the sensors each 5 minutes, for example?

Comment: Currently the main issue is that the screen does not stay off when pushing the standby button, even if the phone is not touched. So I think that turning the screen off is the main issue. Can a "service" check sensors when running in the background and check it every 5 minutes like you said?

Comment: We are willing to pay a person who can help us with this issue.

Comment: Or am I not allowed to ask that? If anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Alex, fill in the contact info in your profile, please. I will try to help you.

Comment: Which info do you need specifically because I already have my e-mail address in there.

Comment: It is hidden for all the users except you. Please mail me to dzigorium@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).